# Why are my buffered points oblong and not circle in SQL Server Management Studio - Spatial Results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, spatial, ssms

When I apply STBuffer(1) to a Point in SQL Server Spatial, they show up as an oblong circle, instead of a perfect circle.  Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selected projection is `Equirectangular`, and not the more familiar `Mercator` that we see in Google Maps & Bing Maps.  Change this and the points will show up as expected.

[image]

More information about map projection here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection

Comment: To sum up the relevant part of the link: Projections can preserve either shape or relative size.  They cannot preserve both.